# Did i miss something on the American put option problem?

Tags: american-options

Maybe this is a stupid question, i dont know, anyhow i recently read this part from an article,

[image]

Can someone explain the part " American put value function ...and the exercise boundary jointly solve a free boundary problem, " i though that the you had to solve for the free boundary problem in order to find the American put value ?

Comment: What you said is exactly what McKean is saying: we can find the put value if we can solve the following free boundary problem [...].

Comment: oh he just said it the other way around right?